# Value of optional type 'User?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'uid' of wrapped base type 'User'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui, option-type

When I try to set the constant 'uid' in a class or struct without force unwrapping I get the error: "Value of optional type 'User?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'uid' of wrapped base type 'User'"

My code when force unwrapping was

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
```

After I edited this code (to avoid force unwrapping) to:

```
 guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        print("no user!")
        return
    }
    let uid = currentUser.uid
```

I got the error "Cannot use instance member 'currentUser' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".

Using guard works in my functions but not classes or structs. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. I would guess you've defined another var `currentUser` before that code executes and the compiler doesn't know which `currentUser` you want.  In many cases, non-optional properties or functions of `currentUser` may need to be accessed after that code so the guard is perfectly acceptable as long as the prior reference to `currentUser` is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message. Read it carefully, and take it at face value.

It complains that you are using an optional instance member named currentUser. And you do have indeed an optional instance member named currentUser. You also have a non-optional local variable named currentUser, but obviously the compiler thinks you want the other one.

Obvious better code would be

```
if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
    // code here…
}
```

Or you could make sure that your local variable doesn’t have the same name as the instance variable.

```
guard let current = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
    // some code
    return
}
```